# Handle an ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE, and then continue routing

Tags: mfc

I need to handle an own MFC message ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE, and then continue routing the message as default.  I trap the message as below, and return 0 to forward and continue routing the message. Is this the right way?

```
// Tab control notifications
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGE_ACTIVE_TAB, OnChangeActiveTab)      

LRESULT CCMyTabView::OnChangeActiveTab(WPARAM wp, LPARAM /*lp*/)
{
  CString str;
  str.Format(_T("AFX_WM_CHANGE_ACTIVE_TAB: %d"), (int)wp);
  // TRACE(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this question relate to `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE`? Please provide a [mcve] (and do make it minimal).

Comment: My primary language is not english. I changed the title and tried my best to improve the question.

Comment: I restored my previous answer, although I still don't understand, what you are after. It may not even address the question you asked.

Comment: The purpose is simple update the output panes, after the user changes the view or a doc.

Answer (score 1):

To get the default handling, you call into the base class implementation. So instead of the `return 0;` statement, return the value returned from the base class implementation. Assuming that `CMyTabView` is derived from [CTabView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983705.aspx), the following implementation would do:

```cpp
LRESULT CCMyTabView::OnChangeActiveTab(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    CString str;
    str.Format(_T("AFX_WM_CHANGE_ACTIVE_TAB: %d"), (int)wp);
    // TRACE(str);
    return CTabView::OnChangeActiveTab(wp, lp);
}
```

In case you are using Visual Studio, and don't care about portability, you could use the [__super](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x.aspx) keyword for convenience:

```cpp
    return __super::OnChangeActiveTab(wp, lp);
```

Comment: that works, but was not enoug in my case. For MDI Doc's I had to move the handler to CMainframe.

Answer (score 1):

I just grepped the source code for MFC... So, my guess is that since your class has a name with "View" in it, then it is derived from CTabView.  If that is the case, then call CTabView::OnChangeActiveTab();

You could also just do

```
__super::OnChangeActiveTab(wp, lp);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation (.cpp) file that defines the member functions for your class, start the message map with the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP macro, then add macro entries for each of your message-handler functions, and complete the message map with the END_MESSAGE_MAP macro.

```
            // example for ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE
            const UINT    wm_Find = RegisterWindowMessage( UINT_MESSAGE )

            BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CMyWnd, CWndClass )
                //{{AFX_MSG_MAP( CMyWnd )
                ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE( wm_Find, OnFind )
                //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
            END_MESSAGE_MAP( )

            LRESULT OnFind (WPARAM,LPARAM)
            {
                return 0;
            }
```